# Calling nonstatic function when TimePicker is done

Tags: java, android, datepicker, static, timepicker

I'm kind of new to Android, and I'm currently struggling with the TimePicker. So, I've got the TimePicker here:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    public String time;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        time = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
        //update global variable
        MockDB.setCheckout(time);
    }
}
```

This is working, but after the user selects a time I want to call a function in the activity the picker is in to change the button colors and text. This is in a function called ReserveProduct that extends AppCompatActivity.

```
public void animateButtons() {
    //picker disappears until next button is clicked
    Button picker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    picker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Button picker1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    picker1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (settingReturn == false) {
        //first button turns gray
        Button bttn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheckIn);
        bttn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_inactive);
        String time = ((MockDB) this.getApplication()).getCheckout();
        bttn1.setText("Check Out: 12:27 PM");
        //new button appears
        Button bttn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheckOut);
        bttn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        settingReturn = true;
    } else {
        //make 2nd button inactive
        Button bttn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheckOut);
        bttn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_inactive);
        String time = ((MockDB) this.getApplication()).getReturn();
        bttn2.setText("Return: 1:27 PM");
        //show new buttons
        Button set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSet);
        set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHome);
        home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

My issue is that this function is not static, so I'm not able to simply call it from the TimePicker class. I can't move the button changing functionality to the TimePicker class because I need to be able to extend AppCompatActivity, but AppCompatActivity and DialogFragment have a conflicting class. I also can't make the animateButtons() class static because then the findViewById() functionality throws an error.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the class first, i.e.

```
(new SomeClass()).someMethod();
```

Comment: I tried this and although it isn't throwing an error anymore, the app is crashing when I hit "ok" in the time picker